# one project cannot be removed in monoDevelop-Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, monodevelop

here's a question about removing one project in MonoDevelop-Unity.

I found one project will be opened with another project is opened. The following picture is the detail:
[image]

The "1"project is opened anytime, whatever I open any other project. And it cannot be closed, the error messages are followed:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by 
 the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Only top level 
 items can be closed.
 (etc....) 
   /BuildAgent/work/9ffd76bfa3f1a926/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide
/MonoDevelop.Components.Commands/CommandManager.cs:1062
```

Anyone could help a little bit?

Thanks!

Comment: Is that "1" project in the same folder as your "mechanim1" project? Also did you create the "1" project?

Comment: Thanks！ I restart the mono, everything is OK. But I think the "1" project is the "mechanima1", it was changed name by me, the mono editor may not tell difference.